# How to show cursor in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, text-cursor

I'm new to Powershell and have to use it now that I am doing a lot in Azure.

When I open the Azure Powershell window, the blinking cursor is not there and it's hard for me to tell where edit.  How do I turn on the cursor?  I have done a lot of searching but have not found the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is a powershell issue which defaults size of the cursor to 0 thus making it invisible. The fix is type the following command in the powershell window

`[Console]::CursorSize = 25`

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Is there a way I can persist the setting?

Comment: Set it in your Powershell profile: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692764.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I found the documentation about creating a profile and got it all done.

Comment: Raney's link required a little digging. If you're low on patience, this worked for me: Use `Test-Path $profile` to see if you have a profile already. If you get "false", use `New-Item -path $profile -type file -force` to make one. It'll tell you where the file is. Find it, open it, and paste `[Console]::CursorSize = 25` in there and you're good! Next azure window you open will have a working cursor.

Comment: They made me upgrade to Windows 10. Now in RDC Manager 2.7, in ISE the cursor disappears. The command above gives me an error "Exception setting "Cursorsize": "The handle is invalid."